# Using a string with .format() as a file name for open()

Tags: python, file, string.format

In a program, I want to create a **text file (.txt)** with a file name that contains a string (that is assigned to a variable called `FileName`). Along with the string in the file name, there is a prefix: "Special File:". In the code I write the prefix as one normally would, but to include the variable-assigned string, I use .format().

Code:

```
FileName = 'XYZ'
ActiveFile = open('Special File: {0}.txt'.format(FileName), 'a')
```

This code works of course, however it creates a **File**, not a Text File.

How can I fix the code so that a text file is created instead of a regular `File`?

Comment: What do you mean by "text file"? The `'a'` mode (as opposed to `'ab'`) always opens a text file. The filename, or how you create it, has nothing to do with anything.

Comment: did you mean txt file?

Comment: Also, there's no such type as `File`. In Python 2.x, both text and binary files are of type `file` (lowercase). In Python 3.x, they're `io.TextIOWrapper` and `io.BufferedReader` (or some subclass thereof), respectively. (PS, it might help to know whether you're using 2.x or 3.x, to guess what you expect from a "text file". In 2.x it just means you get newline translation; in 3.x it means you read and write Unicode instead of bytes.)

Comment: @qqvc: Even if he means that… his code is already doing that, too; it creates a file named `'Special File: XYZ.txt'`. (Unless he's on a platform that gives special meaning to `:` in filenames, like VMS or classic Mac, in which case he's probably getting an error, not any kind of file…)

Comment: @abarnert If 'a' mode always _opens_ a text file, how come a program of mine has created text files using it?

Comment: @Jacob: The `'a'` mode always opens an existing file if present, creates and opens a new file if not. Either way, you've got an opened text file.

Comment: @abarnert Its not opening a txt file always.

Comment: @qqvc: If the filename ends in `.txt`, then yes, it _is_ opening a txt file always. (Except when you give it an invalid path, or try to open a file you don't have permissions to read, or try to create a new file on a CD-ROM, etc., in which case it's raising an exception.)

Comment: @arbarnert I'm not a professional when it comes to file types, but on Windows at least, the file is labeled as a `File`.

Comment: Jacob is my answer solved your problem? Check it please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem here has nothing to do with Python. You actually have created a text file named `Special File: XYZ.txt`. But you shouldn't have, and this is confusing Explorer.

Windows filenames should not contain the `:` character, as explained in [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN. But:

> The shell and the file system have different requirements. It is possible to create a path with the Windows API that the shell user interface is not able to interpret properly.

And this is what you've done. You've created a path with the Windows API (well, Python via MSVCRT via the Windows API) that the shell (aka Windows Explorer) is not able to interpret properly.

The solution is simple: Don't use a colon in your filenames, or any of the other reserved characters, `<>"/\|?*`, and don't break any of the other rules in that MSDN document.

If, in your real program, the `:` comes from data or user input rather than hardcoded into the pathname, the usual ways to deal with this are (a) reject it with an error, or (b) replace any illegal characters with `_` or some other substitution. (For example, in iTunes, a song named `I Die: You Die` will be saved in a file named `01 I Die_ You Die.mp3`.)

---

The reason for this rule here is pretty obvious if you think about it: Windows uses colons in pathnames to separate the drive letter from the rest of the path. So, a name like `C:D` would be ambiguous between "file `D` in drive `C`'s current working directory" vs. "file `C:D` in the current working directory of the current drive".

Answer (score 0):

```
FileName = 'XYZ'
ActiveFile = open('{}.txt'.format(FileName), 'a')
```

It's opening a .txt file with format method.

Comment: How does this answer his question, or solve any possible problem he might be having?

Comment: He wants to create a .txt file with format method. Thats how its solving.

Comment: @qqvc Changing this does nothing.

Comment: It "solves" it in exactly the same way as his existing code (except that it gratuitously breaks 2.6 compatibility). So how could that possibly help?

Comment: @qqvc I'm not creating a file with the format method, unless by that you mean creating a file name with the format method.

Comment: In his question, his method creating a file that is not txt. This one creating a txt file named by what is "FileName" has.

Comment: In his question, his method is creating a file named `'Special File: {0}.txt'.format(FileName)`. Your answer is creating a file named `'{}.txt'.format(FileName)`. Both are obviously going to include what `FileName` has, and end in `'.txt'`. You haven't changed anything except to remove the prefix (and, again, gratuitously break 2.6 compatibility).

Comment: No his method does not creating a TXT file. Did you ever run his codes? Also his codes creating a file named Special File. Not FileName. So Jacob how my answer doesnt change anything?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/H0RBkXsQ

Comment: http://i.hizliresim.com/k1ApPq.jpg